# What's the difference between these RegEx

Tags: regex

1. `(\d+|)` vs `(\d+)?`
2. `[\w\W]` vs `[\d\D]` vs `.`

Is there any difference between these regular regex? Which one should be chosen?

I'm using Javascript.

Comment: See http://regex101.com/

Comment: Or http://rubular.com/ ... and choose the one that is the simplest and easiest to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[\w\W]` and `[\d\D]` are used in languages like JavaScript in which there isn't a dotall option.
It matches all characters, **including** newlines, unlike `.` which matches everything *but* a newline.

```
   \w\W or \d\D   -> matches everything including newline characters
              .   -> matches everything except newline characters unless 
                     's' (dotall modifier) is specified 
(\d+|) or (\d+)?  -> matches 1 or more digits OR any position (null)
                     It could simply be written as '(\d*)'
```

Comment: `multiline` and `dotall` are completely different. `.` will not match a newline with only the `multiline` option set.

Comment: Should just say dotall. My mistake

Comment: I made a mistake missed a "+" in the first line.

Comment: @user1990553 `(\d+)?`. Matches null, OR one or more digits. It is equivalent to `(\d+|)`. You should simply use `(\d*)`.

Answer (score 4):

The second one is quite interesting, and I would like to say something about it:

- `[\w\W]` and `[\d\D]` are equivalent, and they are equivalent to `[\s\S]` also. `\W` is the complement character set for `\w`, and the same applies for `\D` - `\d` pair, and `\S` - `\s` pair. Therefore, when putting together, they will match any character without exception.

  They are usually used when there is no construct to "match any character, *without exception*". JavaScript is one example of such case. There is also a less known and highly confusing construct to do so in JavaScript `[^]`, which is usually invalid in other flavors.
- Dot `.` generally matches any character, **but** new line `\n`. Depending on language, it may exclude more characters.

  For [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt), it excludes `\n`, `\r`, `\u0085`, `\u2028`, and `\u2029`. So a `.` is equivalent to `[^\n\r\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

  For [JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), dot `.` will exclude `\r`, `\u2028`, and `\u2029` in addition to `\n`. So `.` is equivalent to `[^\n\r\u2028\u2029]`

  Some language will have a mode to make `.` matches any character, *without exception*. It is called `DOTALL` mode in Java and Python, `SingleLine` mode in C# and Perl.

The behavior of `.` varies from language to language. Generally, they all agree that `\n` should be excluded in "normal" mode, but they may differ slightly in choosing to exclude more.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which language you're using, so I'm going to assume Perl.

1. `(\d+|)` is equivalent to `(\d*)`. It matches a sequence of 0 or more digits and captures the result into `$1`. `(\d)?` matches 0 or 1 digit. If it matches a digit, it puts it in `$1`; otherwise `$1` will be `undef` (you could rewrite it as `(?:(\d)|)` if you want to eliminate the `?`).
2. `[\w\W]` and `[\d\D]` are equivalent, matching any character. `.` is equivalent to `[^\n]` by default (matching any character but newline). If you really want to match any character, you should use `.` and specify the `/s` flag, which makes `.` match any character.