# How to use regex in String.contains() method in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to check if a String contains the words "stores", "store", and "product" in that order, no matter what is in between them.

I tried using `someString.contains(stores%store%product);` and also `.contains("stores%store%product");`

Do I need to explicitly declare a regex and pass it on the method or can I not pass a regex at all?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

### String.contains

`String.contains` works with String, period. It doesn't work with regex. It will check whether the exact String specified appear in the current String or not.

Note that `String.contains` does not check for word boundary; it simply checks for substring.

### Regex solution

Regex is more powerful than `String.contains`, since you can enforce word boundary on the keywords (among other things). This means you can search for the keywords as *words*, rather than just *substrings*.

Use `String.matches` with the following regex:

```
"(?s).*\\bstores\\b.*\\bstore\\b.*\\bproduct\\b.*"
```

The RAW regex (remove the escaping done in string literal - this is what you get when you print out the string above):

```
(?s).*\bstores\b.*\bstore\b.*\bproduct\b.*
```

The `\b` checks for word boundary, so that you don't get a match for `restores store products`. Note that `stores 3store_product` is also rejected, since digit and `_` are considered part of a word, but I doubt this case appear in natural text.

Since word boundary is checked for both sides, the regex above will search for exact words. In other words, `stores stores product` will not match the regex above, since you are searching for the word `store` without `s`.

`.` normally match any character **except** [a number of new line characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648743/whats-the-difference-between-these-regex/14648811#14648811). `(?s)` at the beginning makes `.` matches any character without exception (thanks to Tim Pietzcker for pointing this out).

Comment: You might want to add `(?s)` to the start of your regex in case the string contains newlines.

Comment: i am checking it in a URL like this>> http://stores.nextag.com/store/4908844/product/1070625777/Exclusive-TI-84-Plus

Comment: can you explain the first backslash here `\\b`

Comment: @vipin8169: In String, you need to double up the ``\`` to specify a single ``\``, so `\\b` will be interpreted as `\b`, as seen in the RAW regex. `\b` matches word boundary, as explained above.

Comment: if need to match ".mydomain." in string. then how would it update the regex. My use case is whether "www.abc.mydomain.in.io" containing the .mydomain. or not

Answer (score 137):

`matcher.find()` does what you needed. Example:

```
Pattern.compile("stores.*store.*product").matcher(someString).find();
```

Comment: Love this one. I find matcher's regex overly complicated.

Answer (score 28):

You can simply use `matches` method of String class.

```
boolean result = someString.matches("stores.*store.*product.*");
```

Comment: You need to start off with `.*` or it'll only match strings beginning with `stores`.

Comment: _Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern._ It seems that @shmosel is right, no?

Comment: Well, it just *matches* but does not check if the string contains the pattern at any position. This is not a solution what OP looks for, I suggest to refine the regexp.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check if a string contains substring or not using regex, the closest you can do is by using find() -

```
    private static final validPattern =   "\\bstores\\b.*\\bstore\\b.*\\bproduct\\b"
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(validPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
    System.out.print(matcher.find()); // should print true or false.
```

Note the difference between matches() and find(), matches() return true if the whole string matches the given pattern. find() tries to find a substring that matches the pattern in a given input string. Also by using find() you don't have to add extra matching like - (?s).* at the beginning and .* at the end of your regex pattern.

Answer (score 3):

As of **Java 11** one can use `Pattern#asMatchPredicate` which returns `Predicate<String>`.

```
String string = "stores%store%product";
String regex = "stores.*store.*product.*";
Predicate<String> matchesRegex = Pattern.compile(regex).asMatchPredicate();

boolean match = matchesRegex.test(string);                   // true
```

The method enables *chaining* with other String predicates, which is the main advantage of this method as long as the `Predicate` offers `and`, `or` and `negate` methods.

```
String string = "stores$store$product";
String regex = "stores.*store.*product.*";

Predicate<String> matchesRegex = Pattern.compile(regex).asMatchPredicate();
Predicate<String> hasLength = s -> s.length() > 20;

boolean match = hasLength.and(matchesRegex).test(string);    // false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "something hear - to - find some to or tows";
    System.out.println("1.result: " + contains("- to -( \\w+) som", test, null));
    System.out.println("2.result: " + contains("- to -( \\w+) som", test, 5));
}
static boolean contains(String pattern, String text, Integer fromIndex){
    if(fromIndex != null && fromIndex < text.length())
        return Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text).find();

    return Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text).find();
}
```

1.result: true

2.result: true

Comment: `fromIndex` is ignored, isn't it? `contains("something", test, 5) => true`