# Issue in displaying toast message in android

Tags: java, android, button, toast

According to my requirement in android, if the user presses only "space" and clicks "post" button a toast should be displayed.
So i have the code as below, but the toast doesnt get displayed.
please can anybody tell why it is not displaying ?

```
   mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);    
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result =mEditText.getText().toString();
         if(result.contains ("\\s"))
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: log "result" and check what you are getting in it before if statement

Comment: show the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use regex with `String.contains` method.
`String.contains` method works with `String`. It doesn't work with `regex`.

See this question for more details:
[How to use regex in String.contains() method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130309/how-to-use-regex-in-string-contains-method-in-java)

By the way,
you should not check for just one space. You should handle any number of spaces.

```
if(result.length()!=0 && result.trim().equals(""))
    ShowToast();
```

Comment: nice move, but if the EditText is empty, it will still show the toast, as i understood @DD wants to show it when only space is entered in the EditText.

Comment: thanks it works :) @VikramSingh but any spaces followed by the text doesnt get trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think contains get you the best result, try this:

```
if(result.equals(" "))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if(result.contains (" "))
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This code handles just one space. Ideally, you should handle any number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have a two way of solutions

1.You should check this condition by " " --> if(result.contains ("\s"))

Example:

```
if(result.contains(" "))
```

2.You Should Check with Pattern

Example:

```
String result =ed.getText().toString();
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
   boolean found = matcher.find();
   if(found)
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Please use any of these solutions.It will work.

Comment: DD for Vikram singh's answers works for only one space. But,you will use my second solution it will show toast for every spaces.

Comment: Vikram singh's solution will work with one space and multiple space also. String.trim() will remove all the white spaces in the beginning and end

Comment: Ok. I thought if enter "arun kumar" this time also will shown the toast. But,Now only i can understand the complete requirement. Sorry vikram singh

Answer (score 0):

I changed the if condition to space and i am getting a Toast message successfully.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           String result =mEditText.getText().toString();
           Log.e("Test Message", result);
           if(result.contains (" "))
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });
}
```

Please try and let me know if you are still facing the issue ...

Thanks