# How to detect readable text in Java using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following Regular Expression: [a-zA-Z]+ to detect if a string contains text but this fails in Java 1.7.
It does work in Notepad++.
What am I missing?

```
String message = "123 foo 567";
if (message.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    System.out.println("Success");
} else
    System.out.println("Fail");

"foo" --> Success
"123 foo" --> Fail
"foo 456" --> fail
```

Comment: This check if the string _matches_ the regular expression, not if it contains instances of it. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15130309/1348195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java API Specification on [`Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29):

> Returns:
>       true if, and only if, **the entire region sequence** matches this matcher's pattern

(emphasis are mine). That is as if you were wrapping your expression in `^...$` in Notepad++.

Use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It would have been nice when this subtlety was mentioned in the documentation for String.matches as well.

Comment: Yeah, they kinda missed that. Internally `String.matches` is using `Matcher.matches()`, if you know that you can make the connection... BUt most people won'T read the sourcecode just to get this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get String.matches work on partial strings instead of the whole string you can  add a .* at start and end of the matching string to undo the effect of ^...$, like in: `.*[a-zA-Z]+.*`