# Regex for matching substring, but not containing word

Tags: regex

I'd like to be able to use a regular expression to match a given string, but not a specific longer word which contains it. Here's an example to better explain:

Given the text:

```
String bellsringing = "The bells are ringing is a String";
```

I want to be able to find all occurences of "ring", that are not part of the word String, not limited to word (can appear inside one). **So the answer would be only "bells(ring)ing" and "(ring)ing".**

I am aware that a program can be used for such a task, but I have come accross the need to find specific strings in large libraries and if the sought string is a substring of a common keyword / literal, I have lots of digging to do and would benefit from the IDE's search using regex function :)

Thanks for any input on this.

Comment: This is probably helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130309/how-to-use-regex-in-string-contains-method-in-java/15130382#15130382

Comment: thanks, but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: what exactly would be the ouput?

Comment: I bolded what the output would be :)

Comment: Is "String" the only text you want to exclude? Or something like "bring", too? You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match the start or end of a word, but differentiating between _in the middle of some words but not others_ could be really hairy.

Comment: let's say I only want to exclude String as excluding multiple words can get ever hairyer :) but yes, the sought string can occur inside the word... searching for a full word or one ending/starting with the text I can do

Comment: Look at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23589204/2684660)** about how to capture a string except in contexts A, B or C. Regexes can't understand whether a group of letters within a word has retained its meaning, so you'll have to somehow make a list of what to accept and what not with this contexts A, B or C technique. It's the long version of Fede's answer.

Comment: Wow... thanks for the link. It made my day. Now I understand @Fede's answer as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression)

If you are using `PCRE` regex then you could use a regex like this:

```
String(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|ring
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zS2eB3/1)**

[image]

The idea of this regex is to fail `string` pattern so it will skip it but will keep `ring`. Btw, if you want to grab the complete word you could use this regex:

```
String(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w*ring\w*)
```

The match information is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [14-21] `ringing`
MATCH 2
1.  [64-71] `ringing`
```

### Other engines

On the other hand, if you are not using `PCRE` you could leverage the **discard pattern** that's a really nice regex trick by doing this:

```
String|(\w*ring\w*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zS2eB3/2)**

[image]

In this case what you do is to match what you **don't want** on the left side of the pattern while you keep **what you want** on the rightest part **using a group**. The discard pattern follows this rule:

```
discard patt1 | discard patt2 | ... | discard pattN | (KEEP THIS PATTERN)
```

Then you have to access to the regex group `\1` or `$1` to grab the saved string. For this case is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [14-21] `ringing`
MATCH 2
1.  [64-71] `ringing`
```

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_sDqRT7tu8TBJUVo) does a good job displaying graphically this technique:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks to @funkwurm's comment, I understand your answer and it's quite nice. However this doesn't help inside a find-and-replace feature of a text editor or an IDE as they look at all the matched groups, therefor it matches also String.

Comment: Combined with @OnlineCop's comment, this actually works :) Thanks, guys

Comment: @AdrianB. yes, that is the disadvantage of the discard technique. I focused on programming instead of text editors where this technique is a weakness.

Comment: Im getting 4 matches in the demo, 2 for ringing and 2 for String

Answer (score 2):

Building off of @Fede's answer, use a negative look-ahead:

```
\b(?!String)\w*ring\w*\b
```

This will start at a word boundary, ensure that it doesn't find `String`, and then match `ring` where it can.

[Working example](http://regex101.com/r/zS2eB3/3)

Comment: Accepted @Fede 's answer as it was more detailed, but here's an upvote

Comment: OnlineCop very clever, I like your approach +1

Comment: Yeah; I'd feel bad if I got the upvote for this; Fede's answer was very thorough (and I even learned something new from it). :-D

Comment: Lol, don't do it. Your answer is valid and good one and shows a different approach. Also I learned from yours too.

Answer (score 0):

```
String|\b(\w*?ring\w*)\b
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.Apply `i` flag.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/39