# Setting Booleans with Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a `BufferedReader` to read a text file line by line. 
I've got a series of three regular expressions to test each line for `numbers` , `capitals` and `special chars`.

If any of them match, I set a `boolean` to true. 
I want to use these booleans later to output a message to the user telling them the findings of the 'scan'.

However, when I come to use the booleans, they are all still set to false, despite me adding numbers, caps etc into the test text file.

If a line in the text file was, say `abC 6` then `numBool` and `capBool` should return true, but not `specialBool`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;

class ReadFile implements Runnable
{
    public void run() 
    {
        String line; 
        Boolean capBool = false;
        Boolean numBool = false;
        Boolean specialBool = false;

        try
        {
            /* ------------- Get Filename ------------- */
            System.out.print("Enter file to scan : ");
            BufferedReader fileGet = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String file_name = fileGet.readLine();
            fileGet.close();

            /* ---------------- Open File ---------- */
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));

            /* --------------- Scan file line by line ----------- */
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.matches("[A-Z]"))
                    capBool = true;
                if(line.matches("[0-9]"))
                    numBool = true;
                if(line.matches("[$&+,:;=?@#|]"))
                    specialBool = true;

                System.out.println(line);
            }

            br.close(); // close reader

            DisplayResults display = new DisplayResults();
            String findings = display.displayFindings(capBool, numBool, specialBool);

            System.out.print(findings);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " - Please check log file for more details");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Exceptions.txt")));
        Runnable r = new ReadFile();
        Thread th = new Thread(r);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Is this because the booleans are being overwritten somehow when I exit the while loop? Or are they never getting set to true because of a faulty regex method?

Comment: For capBool did you mean `[A-Z]` or `[A-Z]*` ?

Comment: Learn to debug it, you can answer most of your own questions there.

Comment: It seems your regular expressions are insufficient. Can you add example lines to your question, and tell us which of them is supposed to result in `true` in each of the booleans?

Comment: have edited my question @RealSkeptic . I don't pretend to be a regex pro, so i'm not surprised if they're the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` means what it looks like it does - checks whether the whole string matches your regex. That however is not what you want most probably, judging by the way you wrote those regexes - what you seem to be looking for is a kind of regexy `contains`.

The sad part is however, there is no alternative pretty syntax to do what you want - see [How to use regex in String.contains() method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130309/how-to-use-regex-in-string-contains-method-in-java). You need to go and rewrite your regexes.

And it shouldn't be that hard. Just surround your ready expressions with `.*` to indicate that what you're looking for can be preceeded or followed by any number of characters - i.e. `[A-Z]` can be changed to `.*[A-Z].*`

Comment: Many thanks! Works perfect , and taught me something useful about regex - cheers!

Comment: Note that this won't work if the string contains multiple lines, because `.` does not match a newline character. To get around this, use `[\\S\\s]*[A-Z][\\S\\s]*`.

Comment: @jsheeran that is a good point, however note the question - he tests "each line", which by definition excludes the possibility of having multiple lines within the string.