# How to search for a string and similar word in a text?

Tags: java, string, contain

I have to lookup for a word "age" and similar word in a text file.

I have following sentence :

- 18 years of age
- man aged 51
- man ages between 25 to 50
- between 5 to 75 years of age.(with dot)
- between 5 to 75 years of age, (with comma)
- agent name is xyz (agent contain age).

[String.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) always return true in each case. My requirement is to pass the first five sentence and it return false in last case.

I will solve this problem by writing some code which contains a bunch of string " age ", " age." , "ages", "aged", " age," etc..

Is there any better way to solve this problem.

Comment: perhaps you should use stemming, or calcuate the edit distance (simmetrics offers that)

Comment: you'll need to use full-text search and text analysis to compute similarities

Comment: something easy to test out with is "LevenshteinDistance - the number of changes needed to change one String into another", Apache StringUtils has an implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use regex, you have to put all the possiblities.

```
string.matches("(?i).*\\bage[ds]?\\b.*");
```

Comment: So, "What is your age?" "Age? 40!" ... would not work.

Comment: now, it would `string.matches("(?i).*\\bage[ds]?\\b.*");`

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution (expensive) would be the following:

1. tokenize each line (e.g., split by " ", or even non-alphanumeric characters, which already removes punctuation).
2. calculate the **edit distance** of each word to the word age
3. if the current word has a small edit distance (e.g., bellow 2), return line

The edit distance of two string is the number of edits (additions, deletions and replacements) that are required to make one string equal to the other. You can find an implementation of edit distance in the [simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) library, or maybe elsewhere, too.

Another option could be to stem the words at step 2 and use contains with the **stemming** of the word age (also expensive).

If you already know all the acceptable answers (or at least their pattern), go for [Avinash Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616337/2516301).

Comment: The source forge version of Simmetrics is a bit out dated. Try https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called a regular expression (or regex)

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130309/how-to-use-regex-in-string-contains-method-in-java) a perfectly detailed definition of regular expressions and use in Java, which can be done with [matches(String Regex) method of String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)).

For your example, it could (normally) be : `myString.matches(".*age? .*")`.

Pay attention in escaping special characters in Java. You can try your regexs [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). I didn't do it in the example above, but you can try :)

In detail :

- .* : the sentence can begin with everything
- age : the sentence must contain 'age'
- ? : age can be followed by zero or one character
- : then a space
- .*: then everything again

Hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, totally. This is why I wrote could, not should.