# How do I check if there's a time inside a string?

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to check if a `String` contains a time, 12 or 24 hour format, using this regex: `.*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9].*` and used `String.matches()`, but it didn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I know `String.matches()` doesn't work the same way `String.contains()` but I read that adding a `.*` at the beginning and end of the regex makes it act that way from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130382/2038087).

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this!

EDIT: An example in which I'm trying to check if a time exists in a String would be like, "The current time in London is 6:00 PM, what is the time in Toronto?", and it would return true because 6:00 PM is inside the `String`.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat`...

Comment: @Reimeus I don't quite understand how I would use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @stribizhev Expression rejects hours > 23, and minutes > 59, but not hours > 11 for AM/PM matching.

Comment: Please don't use expressions like `.*something.*` with `matches()`, when you really mean find `something` using `find()`.

Comment: @stribizhev I used `String.matches()` and `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(String).find()` using the example `String` but for some reason they both return false, even though in the demo, it shows that it should return true.

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/ji9PQr). This should work now: `str.matches("(?i).*\\b(?:(?<twelve>(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?[ ]*[ap]m)|(?<twfour>(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?))\\b.*")`.

Comment: OK, it works now, it's just my IDE added some extra backslashes to avoid escape sequence issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Pattern and Matcher for this answer....

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class IsTimeInString {

    public static void main(String args[]){

         String string = args[0];
         System.out.println(String.format("Is there a time in here:(%1$s)", string));
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9].*");
         Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
         if(m.matches()){
             System.out.println("Yes");
         }else{
             System.out.println("No.");
         }
    }


}
```

Sample outputs...

```
$ java IsTimeInString "hi there"
Is there a time in here:(hi there)
No.

$ java IsTimeInString "hi there 2:15"
Is there a time in here:(hi there 2:15)
Yes

$ java IsTimeInString "hi there 14:15"
Is there a time in here:(hi there 14:15)
Yes
```

Comment: For Java developers, this or @stribizhev's answer works, but for Android developers, this only works because stribizhev's syntax is too complex for Android to use

Comment: @silver2049 *stribizhev*'s answer is easy to retrofit to older Java, aka Android. Check my answer (works for Android too) for extended validation and usage. Both are more complex, true, it's a question of how *strict* you want the matching to be.

Comment: @Andreas the problem is that the grouping syntax used in stribizhev's answer isn't supported as shown [here](http://imgur.com/RlGv4rM)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex that you can use:

```
String pattern = "(?i).*\\b(?:(?<twelve>(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?[ ]*[ap]\\.?m\\.?)|(?<twfour>(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?))\\b.*";
String str = "The current time in London is 6:00 PM, what is the time in Toronto?";
System.out.println(str.matches(pattern);
```

Breakdown:

```
(?i)       # turning on case-insensitive matching
 .*        # match anything in the beginning
  \\b      # match a word boundary
  (?:      # Below is a 12 hour format with AM/PM
    (?<twelve>(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?[ ]*[ap]\\.?m\\.?)
    |      # Below is 24 hour format
    (?<twfour>(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?)
  )
 \\b
.*
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ji9PQr)

Comment: Ready, IDEONE demo now is working and the answer seems complete. Note that this will also find a match if you have 13:45 PM, but I do not think it is a false positive. Else, add the look-ahead back as in my previous regex version: `(?<twfour>(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?(?![ ]*[ap]m))`.

Comment: Change `<twelve>` and `<twfour>` to `:` for pre-Java 7 support (older Android).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String myString = "The current time in London is 6:00 PM";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myString, "\\s+");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date timeShort, timeLong;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String possibleTime = st.nextToken();
        if(possibleTime.matches(".*\\d.*"))
        {
            System.out.println(possibleTime.trim());
            try {
                timeShort = sdf.parse(possibleTime);
                System.out.println("TIME: " + timeShort);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // Not AM/PM Time
            }
            try {
                timeLong = sdf1.parse(possibleTime);
                System.out.println("TIME: " + timeLong);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // Not normal Time
            }
        }
    }
```

result is

> 6:00 PM
>
> TIME: Thu Jan 01 18:00:00 CET 1970

and later as rebuttal evidence try to parse it with JavaTime

Comment: This will even match `6` in `6 bottles of wine` :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Made space before AM/PM optional, since you sometimes see `9:45am`. Also added word boundary check.

Assuming you might want to do the check more than once, it's better to precompile the regular expression.

```
String timeExpr = "\\b" +                      //   word boundary
                  "(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])" +    //   match 0-9, 00-09, 10-19, 20-23
                  ":[0-5][0-9]" +              //   match ':' then 00-59
                  "(?! ?[ap]m)" +              //   not followed by optional space, and 'am' or 'pm'
                  "\\b" +                      //   word boundary
                "|" +                          // OR
                  "\\b" +                      //   word boundary
                  "(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-1])" +       //   match 0-9, 00-09, 10-11
                  ":[0-5][0-9]" +              //   match ':' and 00-59
                  " ?[ap]m" +                  //   match optional space, and 'am' or 'pm'
                  "\\b";                       //   word boundary
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(timeExpr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Note the "not followed by ' am' or ' pm'", otherwise it would match `17:00 PM`.

You can test it like this:

```
String str = "The current time in London is 6:00 PM, what is the time in Toronto?";
if (p.matcher(str).find()) {
    System.out.println("Has time");
} else {
    System.out.println("Has no time");
}
```

Or a more complex example that actually extracts the times:

```
String str2 = "When it is 6:00 PM in London, is it 14:00 in Toronto?";
Matcher m = p.matcher(str2);
if (! m.find())
    System.out.println("Has no time");
else
    do {
        System.out.println("Found time: " + m.group());
    } while (m.find());
```

*Output* running both:

```
Has time

Found time: 6:00 PM
Found time: 14:00
```