# Java contains() method not working properly

Tags: java, string

I'm writing small condition to check if certain character are exist or not in java. This is my string: May i know how much I spent on food?

I'm checking if food string is exist or not, if i check "food" in if condition I'm getting proper response, if i use "Food" or "fOod" or "fOOd" or "fooD" its always going to else block. What I'm doing wrong here:

String food = "may i know how much I spent on food";

```
if(food.contains("Food")) {
    System.out.println("Food Expense is 32");

} else {
    System.out.println("Not Matching");
}
```

Comment: contains is not a case insensitive search; in your example, it looks literally for "Food" with a capital "F"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130309/5647260

Comment: suppose you refer the java doc on `String contains()` method. it is `public boolean contains(CharSequence s)` and it takes only a `CharSequence`

Comment: @RajithPemabandu A `String` **is** a `CharSequence`.

Comment: When you "learn jquery" you'll know that Javascript is a case sensitive search by default too.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the difference in cases. `"Food".equals("food")` will give you false. To solve the problem of cases you can convert everything to lower when searching

```
if (food.toLowerCase().contains("Food".toLowerCase())) {}
```

And you can have any variation of food in the if condition. No need to worry about case sensitivity with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(food.toLowerCase().contains("Food".toLowerCase())) {
System.out.println("Food Expense is 32");

} else {
System.out.println("Not Matching");
}
```

Comment: Advice:  "Try this" answers generally don't get upvotes.  An answer should explain what was wrong with the original code, and how the new code fixes it.  (Contrast the other answer to this question.)