# String matching of a keyword using .contains() in Android

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

```
String a = "Hello my name is Sap";

String b = "HelloisSapmyname";

String c = "Sap is my name";

String d = "Sap";



String keyword = "Sap";
```

when I use `.contains()` it is true for all strings.

How do it get it true for all cases except b?

Note: Adding a space before keyword will not work if the keyword if the first word. Please Help!

**EDIT**: Added all the possible conditions

**SOLUTION**: With help from the other answers I found the solution which satisfies every condition

```
if (a.contains(" "+key+ " ") || a.startsWith(key+" ") 
    || a.equals(key) || a.endsWith(" "+key))
```

Will regex be faster than this?

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use regex in String.contains() method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130309/how-to-use-regex-in-string-contains-method-in-java)

Comment: You could use " Sap" as a keyword (with a space), although it may be better to first split the sting into individual words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simply Regex. \b use for word boundry.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bSap\\b");

String a ="Hello my name is Sap";
Matcher m1 = p.matcher(a);
System.out.println( m1.find());// return true

String b = "HellomynameisSap";
Matcher m2=p.matcher(b);
System.out.println( m2.find());//return false

String c = "Hello Sap my name";
Matcher m3=p.matcher(c);
System.out.println( m3.find());//return true

String d = "Sap";
Matcher m4=p.matcher(d);
System.out.println( m4.find());//return true
```

By default it is case sensitive.
if you want case insensitivity then you have to initialize `Pattern` like this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bsap\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Please check the question now. Will this solution satisfy every condition?

Comment: @ShubhankarPatil yes it satisfy every condition. whenever Sap is in the String as a seprate word. it  returns true.

Comment: @ShubhankarPatil i updated the answer by verifying more cases.It will return true for all cases you described in question.

Comment: Thanks. Can this Matcher be used for matching case insensitively ?

Comment: @ShubhankarPatil by default it iis case sensitive. but you can use this matcher for case insenstivity.

Comment: Not working in android. Its returning true for every case

Comment: @ShubhankarPatil I verified in simple java app and it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182017/discussion-between-khalid-shah-and-shubhankar-patil).

Comment: Working now. Silly mistake

Answer (score 4):

You can split the input `String` into words, convert it to `List` and run `contains` on the `List`:

```
Arrays.asList("Hello my name is Sap".split(" ")).contains("Sap")
```

Comment: Convert a String to an array (using regex), then convert an array into a list and then iterate over all of it once again... This need 3 times as much memory as the original text.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak you don't have to optimize memory usage for such small examples. I'd always prefer readability (unless memory becomes a bottleneck).

Comment: Hi. Your answer works. But can you check my solution? I've edited the question. Please tell me if there is a more efficient way

Comment: @ShubhankarPatil your solution seems correct, but also seems less readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(a.contains(" "+key+" ") || a.startsWith(key) || a.endsWith(key))
```

Comment: You should check for "startsWith" before checking for "contains". I suspect it's going to give you a much better performance in some cases.

Comment: performance wise startsWith is faster than contains, but there will be lesser cases of startsWith being true than contains, so that won't it create an overhead in cases where contains is true? @tanyehzheng

Comment: I agree with you. But given that the overhead is likely to be very small and if "startsWith" happens to be true, it's going to give you a much better performance, I suspect that it's worth it. But of course, without knowing the specific scenario, nobody knows which is faster.

Comment: this doesn't work in this case: String "Hello my name is SapHello"

Answer (score 0):

Simply try the following

```
if(Str.startsWith("Sap ") ||  Str.contains(" Sap")){
    <code>
}
```

Comment: i think you have updated the question recently. When i posted answer to this there was only 2 possibilities were listed.

Answer (score 0):

".contains()" should work.

```
String a = "Hello my name is Sap";
String b = "HelloisSamynamep";
String c = "Sap is my name";
String d = "Sap";
String keyword = "Sap";

System.out.println(a.contains(keyword));
System.out.println(b.contains(keyword));
System.out.println(c.contains(keyword));
System.out.println(d.contains(keyword));

Output -

true
false
true
true
```

If i'm not wrong, ".contains()" uses regex internally.

Comment: You havent tagged it as android. This works in Java 8.