# Regex if line does not contain key words

Tags: java, regex

How would you set up the expression to find that the keywords do not exist in input string?
Key words are: eggs, bacon, cheese

Function is:

```
    if (!line.matches("eggs") || !line.contains("bacon")|| !line.contains("cheese") )
    {
        match=line;
    }

    return matchregex;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried: 1. if (!line.contains("eggs") || !line.contains("bacon")|| !line.contains("cheese") )         //2. if (line.toLowerCase().matches("(.*?cheese:.*)|(.*?eggs:.*)   //3. Ive tried to find examples for the past two days. //4. I noticed that  if (!line.contains("eggs") )  works, but if I try to add anymore words it will not work at all and ignore my keywords completely.

Comment: Look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130309/how-to-use-regex-in-string-contains-method-in-java) and put the code into a method, use that  method to return the opposite of its result

Comment: As a side note: just for checking those three words I would not recommend using a regex. The usual string methods for finding text are faster in that particular case.

Comment: @Sascha Interesting, do you believe that raw performance is a critical factor in this project? :-)

Comment: raw performance is not a factor at this time. I am just wanting to learn how to filter a list out using different methods. I ended up using if (!line.matches(".*\\b(egg|bacon)\\b.*")).  I am now trying to see if two variables can be checked with the "contains". Like variable1 is similiar to variable 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression for matching eggs or bacon or cheese is:

```
(eggs|bacon|cheese)
```

You need to detect when lines don't match, so you can negate the condition something like this:

```
if (!line.matches("(eggs|bacon|cheese)") {
    // Do something
}
```

This matches the entire line. If you want to tell whether the line *contains* any of those words, you would need to match differently—either using `.*` to match the rest of the line, or using `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

I would use: `\b` to mark word boundaries, to ensure you only match `cheese` and don't match `cheesecake`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(eggs|bacon|cheese)\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (!matcher.find()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if (!line.matches(".*\\b(eggs|bacon|cheese)\\b.*")) {
    // Do something
}
```

You have to double up the backslashes to escape them inside a String.

Comment: Hmm, would this not also match for `smeggs` ?

Comment: No, for the first example, the entire line would have to match exactly "eggs". For the subsequent examples, I use `\b` to indicate that there must be a word boundary (non-alpha or end of line).

Answer (score 0):

For regular expressions pretty decent description is available from [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Also try this [website](https://regexr.com/) to try out your pattern. It will allow you to quickly view how it behaves.

> **public static boolean matches(String regex,
>                                 CharSequence input)**
>
> Compiles the given regular expression and attempts to match the given
>   input against it.
>
> An invocation of this convenience method of the form
>
> ```
>  Pattern.matches(regex, input);
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the expression
>
> ```
>  Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()
> ```
>
> If a pattern is to be used multiple times, compiling it once and
>   reusing it will be more efficient than invoking this method each time.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - regex - The expression to be compiled
> - input - The character sequence to be matched
>
> Returns:
>
> - whether or not the regular expression matches on the input
>
> Throws:
>
> - PatternSyntaxException - If the expression's syntax is invalid