# Search on a particular line using Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am new with Regular Expression and might be my question is very basic one.

I want to create a regular expression that can search an expression on a particular line number.

eg.
 I have data

```
"\nerferf erferfre erferf 12545" + 
"\ndsf erf" + 
"\nsdsfd refrf refref" + 
"\nerferf erferfre erferf 12545" + 
"\ndsf erf" + 
"\nsdsfd refrf refref" + 
"\nerferf erferfre erferf 12545" + 
"\ndsf erf" + 
"\nsdsfd refrf refref" + 
"\nerferf erferfre erferf 12545" +
```

And I want to search the number 1234 on 7th Line. It may or may not be present on other lines also.

I have tried with

```
"\\n.*\\n.*\\n.*\\n.*\\n.*\\n.*\\d{4}"
```

but am not getting the result.

Please help me out with the regular expression.

Comment: I think your linefeed should come at the end of the line, and not at the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your `newline` character should be placed at the end of the lines. That way, picturing a particular line would be easier. *Below explanation is based on this modification.*

Now, to get to 7th line, you would first need to skip the first 6 line, that you can do with `{n,m}` quantifier. You don't need to write `.*\n` 6 times. So, that would be like this:

```
(.*\n){6}
```

And then you are at 7th line, where you can match your required digit. That part would be something like this:

```
.*?1234
```

And then match rest of the text, using `.*`

So, your final regex would look like:

```
(?s)(.*\n){6}.*?1234.*
```

So, just use [`String#matches(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method with this regex.

P.S. `(?s)` is used to enable single-line matching. Since dot`(.)` by default, does not matches the newline character.

To print something you matched, you can use capture groups:

```
(?s)(?:.*\n){6}.*?(1234).*
```

This will capture `1234` if matched in *group 1*. Although it seems unusual, that you capture an exact string that you are matching - like capturing `1234` is no sense here, as you know you are matching `1234`, and not against `\\d`, in which case you might be interested in exactly what are those digits.

Comment: Thanks. For searching it is skipping first 6 lines but when it is printing, it is printing first six lines also.

Comment: @NiteshGupta. Just capture whatever you want to print in a group. What do you want to print anyways?

Comment: Can't we remove the unwanted lines from regular expressions only. Just a thought. I don't know much about regular expressions.

Comment: @NiteshGupta. Of course you can do, but again the question - Do you just want that 7th line back? If yes, then capture it in a group. That's it. I've edited my answer a little bit.

Comment: Do note that `.` in Java [excludes more than just `\n`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648743/whats-the-difference-between-these-regex/14648811#14648811). The current regex will exclude some character from the whole string (if it matters). Another thing is that you don't need to search more after you have found `1234`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\n.*){6}\\n.*\\d{4}" );
System.out.println(p.matcher(s).find());
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is better not solved with regex alone. Start by splitting the string on a newline character, to get an array of lines:

```
String[] lines = data.split("\\n");
```

Then, to execute the regex on line 7:

```
try {
    String line7 = lines[6];
    // do something with it
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    System.error.println("Line not found");
}
```

Hope this is a start for you.

Edit: I'm not a pro in Regex but I would try with this one:

```
"(\\n.*){5}(.*)"
```

Sorry if this isn't the correct Java syntax but this should capture 5 new lines + data first, so that's six lines gone, and the data itself should be available in the second capture group (including newline). If you want to exclude the newline in front:

```
"(\\n.*){5}\\n(.*)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am learning RegEx and want to solve this issue with that only. I can't split the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(^.*\r\n)(^.*\r\n)(^.*\r\n)(^.*\r\n)(^.*\r\n)(^.*\r\n)(^.*)(1234)
```