# Whats the difference between [\s\S]*? and .*? in Java regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have developed a regular expression to identify a block of xml inside a text file. The expression looks like this (I have removed all java escape slashes to make it read easy):

```
<\?xml\s+version="[\d\.]+"\s*\?>\s*<\s*rdf:RDF[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\s*\/\s*rdf:RDF\s*>
```

Then I optimised it and replaced `[\s\S]*?` with `.*?` It suddenly stopped recognising the xml.

As far as I know, `\s` means all white-space symbols and `\S` means all non white-spaced symbols or `[^\s]` so `[\s\S]` logically should be equivalent to `.` I didn't use greedy filters, so what could be the difference?

Comment: By default `.` doesn't match line separators. It may match all characters (including line separators) if you use `Patter.DOTALL` flag. `[\s\S]` is set which includes all whitespaces \s and all non-whitespaces \S, effectively representing all characters (including line separators).

Comment: The trailing ? contributes nothing in both cases.

Comment: A very related one: [*What's the difference between these RegEx*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648811/3832970)

Comment: Fantastic question, I'm really surprised it doesn't have more upvotes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The regular expressions `.` and `\s\S` are not equivalent, since `.` doesn't catch line terminators (like new line) by default.

According to the [oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef), `.` matches

> Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

while a line terminator is any of the following:

> - A newline (line feed) character (`'\n'`),
> - A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character (`"\r\n"`),
> - A standalone carriage-return character (`'\r'`),
> - A next-line character (`'\u0085'`),
> - A line-separator character (`'\u2028'`), or
> - A paragraph-separator character (`'\u2029`).

The two expressions are not equivalent, as long as the necessary flags are not set. Again quoting the oracle website:

> If [`UNIX_LINES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES) mode is activated, then the only line terminators
>   recognized are newline characters.
>
> The regular expression `.` matches any character except a line
>   terminator unless the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag is specified.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) is a sheet explaining all the regex commands.

Basically, `\s\S` will pickup all characters, including newlines. Whereas `.` does not pickup line terminators per default (certain flags need to be set to pick them up).

Comment: Yes, every \ has been double escaped. I have removed double slashes just to make it easy to read. The expression works, but stops to work as soon as I replace `[\s\S]*?` with `.*?` so difference should be there.

Comment: this is real expression: `<\\?xml\\s+version=\"[\\d\\.]+\"\\s*\\?>\\s*<\\s*rdf:RDF[^>]*>[\\s\\S]*?<\\s*\\/\\s*rdf:RDF\\s*>`

Comment: This is not true. `.` may escape new lines, depending on certain flags. Have a look at my answer for all the details..

Comment: @Neuron the source I quoted states that `.` will not catch newlines. That's what I was going off of. I now realize its probably not as credible as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

it is like in javascript although i don't get use to java, but java is a type of program and it is very useful in our real life.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).